# Related Rates Oil Spill

Tags: calculus, related-rates

I was given this question, but was unable to figure out how to solve it as I was given very few values:

Assume that oil spilled from a ruptured tanker forms a circular oil slick whose radius increases at a constant rate of $0.42$ feet per minute. Estimate the rate at which the area of the spill is increasing when the diameter of the spill is $240$ feet.

(I was also supposed to leave the answer in terms of $\pi$).

However, I don't know where to start. I know that I am solving for $\frac{dA}{dt}$ and radius = $120$ as well as $\frac{dr}{dt} = 0.42$, but that is it. Does anyone have any hints for me? (I don't want a full solution just hints as to how I can better understand)

Comment: You need to relate the variables before relating their rates of change.  So what are the variables, and how are they related?

Comment: You have that the circular area is $A = \pi r^{2}$, and thus $\frac{dA}{dt} = 2 \pi r  \frac{dr}{dt}$.

Comment: So if I plug everything in I get 100.8(pi) ft/min. Thanks for your help